# Non-jailbreak VNC server for iOS? Remotelly use an iOS device?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, vnc

I know there is an existing app named veency that converts the iPhone/iPad in a VNC server. With another program like tightvnc on the mac or windows, you can remotely use an iOs device from your windows/mac. The problem is, I cannot find any existing app or program that does that on an normal iOS device (not jailbreaked). What I find is the opposite, programs that remotely use a desktop computer from the iPad.

Does anyone know any app or method to turn an iOS device in a VNC server?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Did you have a look on GitHub?

Comment: What do you mean? I searched for a long time for an already existing program that did the same as veency but I could not find it.  It does not need to be in the app store, I could install it myself if I had the source project.

Comment: Sorry, I thought you wanted to know how to code this. This isn't really a programing question. Move this to Superuser.

Comment: Try splashtop. You can access your desktop from your iPad. Does not require a jailbreak either.

Comment: I want the exact opposite of spashtop. I do not want to access my computer through my iPad. I want to access my iPad through my computer.

Comment: I know a Windows application called [iTools](http://itools.hk/cms/english/index.html), it should have an English version too. With this application, you can see your iPad's screen on your PC, no jailbroken required.

Comment: It IS possible. If you can jailbreak you can use Veency which is standard VNC. Otherwise you'd need to roll your own solution(Apple will never allow this in the store). apperian.com/remote-control-for-ios I did work on that app, but can't give up the recipe[NDA].

Comment: What I can tell you is that this is possible, but very involving. Here is a video to show how iPhone X is remotely viewed and controlled. https://youtu.be/Y1TY5Px1718

Answer (score 1):

Try http://www.reflectionapp.com

or http://www.airserverapp.com

they mirror the screen like the apple tv.

Hope this helps.

Comment: i can't find why airserver has any value.

Comment: Neither of these will do what the poster has asked for, which is a *server* that runs on an iphone.